# book table of contents: avoid page breaks after parts

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

I have a book with three parts, each introduced with \part{}, and using custom part pages that add a graphic to the Part page. e.g.,

```
\part[Exploratory and Hypothesis-testing Methods]%
 {Exploratory and Hypothesis-testing Methods\\[4ex]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{front/fig/partmap2}
}
```

In the table of contents, I get an extremely bad break that leaves Part II on a single line at the end of a page.  How can I avoid this?

[image]

I can't see any easy way to prepare a MWE example for this but can provide more details if this would be helpful.

Note added in edit: This book uses the publisher-supplied class file, `krantz.cls` rather than `book.cls`. The relevant section of code for doing the TOC entries is:

```
\def\draw@part#1#2{%
  \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
  \vskip1em plus\p@
  \@tempdima1.5em
  \begingroup
    \parindent\z@\rightskip\@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \bfseries
    \leavevmode
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \hskip-\leftskip
    {#1\hfil}\nobreak
      \if@pdf
      \else
        \hfil\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}%
\fi
    \par
    \penalty\@highpenalty\endgroup}

\let\toc@draw\relax
%
\def\l@part#1#2{% 
\toc@draw
 \gdef\toc@draw{\draw@part{\large #1}{\large #2}}}
```

Comment: Leave this adjustment when you're sure that the document is in final form, first of all, because addition or removal of material might make the adjustment obsolete. Place `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak}` just before the `\part` command you wish to move to the next page in the TOC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The table of contents of any document usually confirms Murphy's law: *if something can go wrong, it will*. Your case is exemplary!

The first rule to keep in mind is *don't panic*! (And remember to carry a towel with you.)

Whether the table of contents has bad breaks should not be a concern until the document is in its final form and we have decided pretty much all about typographic questions: insertion or removal of material can (and will, according to Murphy's law) change any of the clever adjustments we made for pushing a title from the second page of the table of contents to the first or conversely.

So, suppose we are at the final stage and we look at the table of contents. Oh, dear! The title of a part sits at the bottom of the first page and the relative contents is listed at the top of the second page!

1. Relax and rejoice! Our document is finished and just need some icing.
2. Go to the point where the `\part` command is issued and type, just before it,

   ```
   %%% Down with Murphy's law
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak}
   %%% :-)

   \part[Exploratory and Hypothesis-testing Methods]%
    {Exploratory and Hypothesis-testing Methods\\[4ex]
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{front/fig/partmap2}% <--- don't forget this %
    }
   ```
3. Run LaTeX twice.
4. Relax again! Our part title is on its way to the second page!

Instead of `\pagebreak` you could use `\newpage`; the difference is that with the former command TeX will try filling up the page, whereas with the latter it will truncate it. Take your pick.

Adding a distinctive series of comments surrounding these typographical adjustments will make it easier to find them when you'll be preparing the second edition of your beautiful book. The relentless Murphy's law will strike again, making most of the adjustments we made for the first edition obsolete, so having an easy way for finding them will help in removing them and add the ones we need.

Comment: This is a great answer.  The book is nearly in final form, and has to be submitted in camera-ready form. The TOC won't change in copy-editing, except possibly for page numbers, but my editor commented on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something strange is happening here, and I am curious about which document class is being used by the OP.  Many of the most common classes for producing books, indeed, automatically take care of discouraging, or even prohibiting, such bad page breaks in the table of contents; in particular, a page break after the ToC line for a part title should never occur with any of the *book*, *memoir*, *scrbook*, and *scrreprt* classes (among the others).

Consider, for example, the *book* standard LaTeX document class: it defines the `\l@part` command (the command which is responsible for typesetting the ToC line for a part title) as follows:

```
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

(see `classes.dtx`, code lines 1152-1169).  As you can see, a `\nobreak` is inserted after the line itself (code line 1163; see also the comment right above it: “Prevent a pagebreak immediately after this entry”).

By means of the `\showlists` diagnostic command, we can check that the vertical list which is produced, at least in ordinary circumstances, by the `\tableofcontents` command actually does not include any legal breakpoint between the line for the part title and the following one.  Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \showboxbreadth = 1000
    \showboxdepth = 1
\tableofcontents
    \showlists
\endgroup

\part{The First Part}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]
\section{One Two}
\lipsum[3]
\section{One Three}
\lipsum[4]

\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Two One}
\lipsum[6]
\section{Two Two}
\lipsum[7]
\section{Two Three}
\lipsum[8]

\part{The Second Part}

\chapter{Three}
\lipsum[9]
\section{Three One}
\lipsum[10]
\section{Three Two}
\lipsum[11]
\section{Three Three}
\lipsum[12]

\chapter{Four}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Four One}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Four Two}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Four Three}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Below we reproduce a couple of excerpts from the transcript file it yields, with a few comments added.

This is the tract of the vertical list where the title of the first part occurs:

```
\penalty 10000      % <<< Before part 1
\glue 40.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.71869
\hbox(8.28131+0.0)x345.0, glue set 219.0308fil
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 I
.\glue 13.4967
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 T
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 h
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 e
.\glue 4.4989 plus 2.24945 minus 1.49963
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 F
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 i
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 r
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 s
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 t
.\glue 4.4989 plus 2.24945 minus 1.49963
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 P
.\kern-0.37491
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 a
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 r
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 t
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(7.78143+0.0)x20.91992, glue set 14.17157fil []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) -15.49623
.\glue(\rightskip) 15.49623
\penalty 10000      % <<< After part 1
\glue 9.99756 plus 1.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.0989
\hbox(6.9011+0.0)x345.0, glue set 291.88933fil
.\glue(\leftskip) 14.99634
.\glue -14.99634
.\hbox(6.48453+0.0)x14.99634, glue set 9.24774fil []
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 O
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(6.48453+0.0)x17.82068, glue set 12.07208fil []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) -15.49623
.\glue(\rightskip) 15.49623
\penalty 301        % <<< After chapter 1
\glue 0.0 plus 0.2
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.1128
\hbox(6.8872+0.0)x345.0, glue set 252.63364fill
.\glue(\leftskip) 37.99074
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x14.99634
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\glue -37.99074
.\hbox(6.4151+0.0)x22.9944, glue set 10.21974fil []
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 O
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\glue 3.33252 plus 1.66626 minus 1.11084
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 O
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\penalty 10000
.\leaders 0.0 plus 1.0fill []
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(6.4151+0.0)x15.49623, glue set 10.49745fil []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) -25.49379
.\glue(\rightskip) 25.49379
\glue 0.0 plus 0.2
```

etc. etc.  You see a `\penalty 10000` before the title of the first part (where I have added the comment `% <<< Before part 1`): this is a special setting, which holds just for the first line of the ToC, to avoid a page break immediatly after the title “Contents”; indeed, we shall see in a moment that the normal setting above the line for a part title is actually to *encourage* a page break.  Rather, note the `\penalty 10000` that follows the same line (the spot marked `% <<< After part 1`): as you can see, there is simply no breakpoint between the line that says “The First Part” and the one containing “One”, which is the title of the first chapter.  Note also the `\penalty 301` that follows the line for a chapter title (where the comment `% <<< After chapter 1` has been added): a page break between the chapter line and the line for the first section within that chapter (section “One One”) *is* allowed, but it is assessed a pretty high penalty.

Now, let us have a look to what happens at the second part title.  We also include one line above it.

```
\hbox(6.8872+0.0)x345.0, glue set 244.27457fill
.\glue(\leftskip) 37.99074
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x14.99634
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\glue -37.99074
.\hbox(6.4151+0.0)x22.9944, glue set 10.21974fil []
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 T
.\kern-0.83313
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 w
.\kern-0.27771
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\glue 3.33252 plus 1.66626 minus 1.11084
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 T
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 h
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\penalty 10000
.\leaders 0.0 plus 1.0fill []
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(6.4151+0.0)x15.49623, glue set 10.49745fil []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) -25.49379
.\glue(\rightskip) 25.49379
\penalty -301       % <<< Before part 2
\glue 22.4945 plus 1.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.71869
\hbox(8.28131+0.0)x345.0, glue set 200.54782fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 I
.\kern0.37491
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 I
.\glue 13.4967
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 T
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 h
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 e
.\glue 4.4989 plus 2.24945 minus 1.49963
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 S
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 e
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 c
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 o
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 n
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 d
.\glue 4.4989 plus 2.24945 minus 1.49963
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 P
.\kern-0.37491
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 a
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 r
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/12 t
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(7.78143+0.0)x20.91992, glue set 14.17157fil []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) -15.49623
.\glue(\rightskip) 15.49623
\penalty 10000      % <<< After part 2
\glue 9.99756 plus 1.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.0989
\hbox(6.9011+0.0)x345.0, glue set 282.52356fil
.\glue(\leftskip) 14.99634
.\glue -14.99634
.\hbox(6.48453+0.0)x14.99634, glue set 9.24774fil []
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 h
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 r
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(6.48453+0.0)x17.82068, glue set 6.32349fil []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) -15.49623
.\glue(\rightskip) 15.49623
\penalty 301
\glue 0.0 plus 0.2
```

etc. etc.  Again, there is no way to break the page between the part title (“The Second Part”) and the subsequent chapter title (“Three”); but, this time, we can also see that a page break is strongly recommended (`\penalty -301`, marked by the comment `% <<< Before part 2`) *before* the part title itself.  Actually, the *book* class does the same before the ToC lines for chapter titles, as you can readily check.

Similar tests can be made for all the most common document classes, including, as remarked above, *memoir*, *scrbook*, and *scrreprt*, or you can directly study how they define the relevant commands: all behave in the same way (actually, the **KOMA-Script** classes use a `\penalty` of 20010, instead of the usual 10000).  So, I am wondering why the page break described in the question ever occurs: it might be a clue that hints at a possible different problem, that should be identified and cured.  Unfortunately, the question lacks sufficient information in this regard.

Comment: I supplied details about the `krantz.cls` used in formatting the TOC lines

Comment: @user101089: I don’t know this class, but from the code excerpt you provides it looks like it deliberately _permits_ a page break in the ToC right below an entry for a part title, albeit it discourages it rather strongly (`\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}` before the entry and `\penalty\@highpenalty` after it).  Indeed, given this combination, your page must have very little flexibility in it to produce such a bad break.  Anyway, if your publisher doesn’t like these breaks, I think they should modify their class, rather than asking their authors to make up for them manually.